The relation between gradient norm and distance to the closest maximum
Let $M$ be a compact connected Rieamannian manifold and let $f\in C^\infty(M)$. I know that, since the gradient points to the nearest local maximum, $\exp_x(t\nabla f(x))$ is a geodesic starting at $x$ and pointing to $y$, the closest maximum to $x$.
I have an intuition that $d(x,y)\geq \|\nabla f(x)\|$. Is that true?
Furthermore, I am specially interested on the analytical properties of $t\mapsto f(\exp_x(t\nabla f(x))$ for a fixed $x$. Is this map non decreasing?

For 2.) the answer is that it can be neither. For example $f(x)=x^3/3$. if we take the point $x=3$, $t\mapsto \exp_x(t \nabla f(x))$ goes from $-3$ to $6$. and $f$ is neither concave nor convex in this interval.

Consider the mapping $\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto f(x) := e^{- x^2}$. It is clear given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, (i) $0$ is the maximum point of $f$ which is closest to $x$ and (ii) $|f'(x)| = 2 |x| e^{-x^2}$. Any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $e^{x^2} < 2$ is a counter-example to your proposed bound. Of course, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a compact, connected Riemannian manifold, but it is easy to use bump functions in order to apply this idea to construct an explicit counter-example.

@Gomes93  Why did you delete your last question with the vector field on the circle ? It was interesting and I may have been able to help you.

@Abezhiko because I understood what was wrong. I was defining the flow in a wrong manner. The curves that I was considering weren't integral curves.
